# Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed

Tags: perl, hashref, arrayref

I am very new to perl and I have been given the task of maintaining a webpage. I have found a bug that I do not know how to fix.

The perl script stops on the following code.

```
my @failedTests = (sort(keys ($TestResultsData{$currPlatform}{$currDate}{failedtests})));
while ( @failedTests )
{
 ...
```

The error message is:

```
Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref.
```

Can that line of code be re-written so that it works?

Comment: Its defined like this
`my %TestResultsData;`
outside of the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `$TestResultsData{$currPlatform}{$currDate}{failedtests}` is a blessed hashref. `keys` cowardly refuses to operate on blessed hashrefs because it would break the illusion of encapsulation and overloading.

(Older versions of Perl wouldn't accept a hashref at all - you needed to pass it a proper hash.)

Try manually dereferencing the hashref into a hash using:

```
my @failedtests = sort keys %{ $TestResultsData{$currPlatform}{$currDate}{failedtests} };
```

Comment: This worked! ... time to do some more reading on hashes. Thank you!

Comment: Also, because it means the object could have overridden `@{}` or `%{}`.

Comment: Note that `keys $ref` is experimental, so `keys %{ $ref }` is a good idea either way.